# How do I calculate the height of my tabs with jquery to push footer down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have set up some tabs with which are absolutely positioned, due to this my footer wont push down. I don't want to set the tabs container to a height in my css as the content height will vary.

I want to find a way of calculating the content div and then applying the style to my .tabs class so that the footer will push down below the content of my tabs, giving it an height. Can someone help a jquery/javascript novice

here is my html:

```
<article class="tabs">
    <section class="current">
        <h3>Documents</h3>
        <div>
            <p >content</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Info</h3>
        <div>
            <p>content1</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Credentials</h3>
        <div>
            <p>A credentials tab content2</p>
        </div>

    </section>
</article>
```

here is my script so far:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        // Fast and dirty
        $('article.tabs section > h3').click(function(){
            $('article.tabs section').removeClass('current');
            $(this)
            .closest('section').addClass('current');
        });
    });

</script>
```

UPDATE: `$(".tabs .current").find("div").height();
    $(".tabs").css("height"," .height");`

i'VE tried adding this to my script , it adds a style to my tabs div as i want but it isn't working out the height of the content div. SO the first art is wrong how do I calculate the height of the div where the content is ? and then apply it the bottom part of the code to add the height to the inline style of my tabs div.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the $.height function to get the height of the tabs?

**Update:** Make sure that you fire $.height after whatever code you run to set up the tabs.  Also, make sure that the target of the invokation is a selector for the tabs container, not just an individual tab.

Comment: $(".tabs.current").find("div").height();  
$(".tabs").css("height","$.height");                             I've tried this, but this only returns a blank style to the tabs div, the height isn't been calculated of my content div, where am i going wrong?